# Ошибка чтения яндекс почты из python с помощью "imap"

Tags: python, imap

Пытаюсь прочесть почту в яндексе через imap.
В письме видно отправителя, получателя и многое другое, но в теле письма какая то белиберда.
Вот выдержка из тела письма

```
Content-Type: text/plain;

    charset="utf-8"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64



DQrQkdC70LDQs9C+0LTQsNGA0LjQvCDQstCw0YEg0LfQsCDRgNC10LPQuNGB0YLR

gNCw0YbQuNGOINCyINC70LjRh9C90L7QvCDQutCw0LHQuNC90LXRgtC1ISDQlNC7

0Y8g0LLRhdC+0LTQsCDQsiDQu9C40YfQvdGL0Lkg0LrQsNCx0LjQvdC10YIsICDQ

v9C10YDQtdC50LTQuNGC0LUg0L/QviDRgdGB0YvQu9C60LU6IMKgaHR0cHM6Ly9l

cG9saXMuYWNrby5ydS9wZXJzb25hbC91c2VyQWN0aXZhdGUucGhwP2VtYWlsPXRy

eXMwMDFAbWFpbGxpZmUucnUmY29kZT0xNjMwODUmYmFja3VybD0NCiDQuCDQstCy

0LXQtNC40YLQtSDQutC+0LQg0LLQsNGI0LXQs9C+INC60LvRjtGH0LAg0Y3Qu9C1

0LrRgtGA0L7QvdC90L7QuSDQv9C+0LTQv9C40YHQuDogMTYzMDg1Lg0K0J/QvtGB

0LvQtSDQsNCy0YLQvtGA0LjQt9Cw0YbQuNC4INCy0Ysg0YHQvNC+0LbQtdGC0LUg

0LjQt9C80LXQvdC40YLRjCDQv9Cw0YDQvtC70Ywg0LTQu9GPINCy0YXQvtC00LAg

0LIg0LvQuNGH0L3Ri9C5INC60LDQsdC40L3QtdGCLiAg0JjQvdGE0L7RgNC80LDR

htC40Y8g0LIg0LTQsNC90L3QvtC8INC/0LjRgdGM0LzQtSDRj9Cy0LvRj9C10YLR

gdGPINC60L7QvdGE0LjQtNC10L3RhtC40LDQu9GM0L3QvtC5INC4INC/0YDQtdC0

0L3QsNC30L3QsNGH0LXQvdCwINGC0L7Qu9GM0LrQviDQtNC70Y8gINCy0LDRgS4g

0J3QtSDQv9C10YDQtdC00LDQstCw0LnRgtC1INC4INC90LUg0YHQvtC+0LHRidCw

0LnRgtC1INC40L3RhNC+0YDQvNCw0YbQuNGOINC+INCy0LDRiNC10Lwg0LrQu9GO

0YfQtSDRjdC70LXQutGC0YDQvtC90L3QvtC5INC/0L7QtNC/0LjRgdC4ICDRgtGA

0LXRgtGM0LjQvCDQu9C40YbQsNC8ISAtLS0g0J/QkNCeICLQkNCh0JrQni3QodCi

0KDQkNCl0J7QktCQ0J3QmNCVIi4NCg==



--------_19169_-917240200_470060

Content-Type: text/html;

    charset="utf-8"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64



PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD4NCjxtZXRhIGh0dHAtZXF1aXY9IkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIg

Y29udGVudD0idGV4dC9odG1sOyBjaGFyc2V0PXV0Zi04IiAvPg0KPG1ldGEgaHR0

cC1lcXVpdj0iWC1VQS1Db21wYXRpYmxlIiBjb250ZW50PSJJRT1FZGdlIiAvPg0K

PG1ldGEgbmFtZT0iZm9ybWF0LWRldGVjdGlvbiIgY29udGVudD0idGVsZXBob25l

PW5vIiAvPg0KPHN0eWxlIHR5cGU9InRleHQvY3NzIj4NCmJvZHl7bWFyZ2luOjA7

cGFkZGluZzo4cHg7fQ0KcHtsaW5lLWhlaWdodDoxLjE1O21hcmdpbjowO3doaXRl

LXNwYWNlOnByZS13cmFwO30NCm9sLHVse21hcmdpbi10b3A6MDttYXJnaW4tYm90

dG9tOjA7fQ0KaW1ne2JvcmRlcjpub25lO30NCmxpPnB7ZGlzcGxheTppbmxpbmU7

fQ0KPC9zdHlsZT4NCjwvaGVhZD4NCjxib2R5Pg0KPHA+PHNwYW4gc3R5bGU9ImJh

Y2tncm91bmQtY29sb3I6ICNmZmZmZmY7Y29sb3I6ICMwMDAwMDA7Zm9udC1mYW1p

bHk6IEFyaWFsO2ZvbnQtc2l6ZTogMTFwdDtmb250LXN0eWxlOiBub3JtYWw7Zm9u

dC13ZWlnaHQ6IG5vcm1hbDsiPtCR0LvQsNCz0L7QtNCw0YDQuNC8INCy0LDRgSDQ

t9CwINGA0LXQs9C40YHRgtGA0LDRhtC40Y4g0LIg0LvQuNGH0L3QvtC8INC60LDQ

sdC40L3QtdGC0LUhINCU0LvRjyDQstGF0L7QtNCwINCyINC70LjRh9C90YvQuSDQ

utCw0LHQuNC90LXRgiwgINC/0LXRgNC10LnQtNC40YLQtSDQv9C+INGB0YHRi9C7

0LrQtTogwqBodHRwczovL2Vwb2xpcy5hY2tvLnJ1L3BlcnNvbmFsL3VzZXJBY3Rp

dmF0ZS5waHA/ZW1haWw9dHJ5czAwMUBtYWlsbGlmZS5ydSZjb2RlPTE2MzA4NSZi

YWNrdXJsPTwvc3Bhbj48L3A+DQo8cD4g0Lgg0LLQstC10LTQuNGC0LUg0LrQvtC0

INCy0LDRiNC10LPQviDQutC70Y7Rh9CwINGN0LvQtdC60YLRgNC+0L3QvdC+0Lkg

0L/QvtC00L/QuNGB0Lg6IDE2MzA4NS48L3A+DQo8cCBzdHlsZT0iYmFja2dyb3Vu

ZC1jb2xvcjogI2ZmZmZmZjtjb2xvcjogIzAwMDAwMDtmb250LWZhbWlseTogQXJp

YWw7Zm9udC1zaXplOiAxMXB0O2ZvbnQtc3R5bGU6IG5vcm1hbDtmb250LXdlaWdo

dDogbm9ybWFsOyI+PHNwYW4gc3R5bGU9ImJhY2tncm91bmQtY29sb3I6ICNmZmZm

ZmY7Ij7Qn9C+0YHQu9C1INCw0LLRgtC+0YDQuNC30LDRhtC40Lgg0LLRiyDRgdC8

0L7QttC10YLQtSDQuNC30LzQtdC90LjRgtGMINC/0LDRgNC+0LvRjCDQtNC70Y8g

0LLRhdC+0LTQsCDQsiDQu9C40YfQvdGL0Lkg0LrQsNCx0LjQvdC10YIuICDQmNC9

0YTQvtGA0LzQsNGG0LjRjyDQsiDQtNCw0L3QvdC+0Lwg0L/QuNGB0YzQvNC1INGP

0LLQu9GP0LXRgtGB0Y8g0LrQvtC90YTQuNC00LXQvdGG0LjQsNC70YzQvdC+0Lkg

0Lgg0L/RgNC10LTQvdCw0LfQvdCw0YfQtdC90LAg0YLQvtC70YzQutC+INC00LvR

jyAg0LLQsNGBLiDQndC1INC/0LXRgNC10LTQsNCy0LDQudGC0LUg0Lgg0L3QtSDR

gdC+0L7QsdGJ0LDQudGC0LUg0LjQvdGE0L7RgNC80LDRhtC40Y4g0L4g0LLQsNGI

0LXQvCDQutC70Y7Rh9C1INGN0LvQtdC60YLRgNC+0L3QvdC+0Lkg0L/QvtC00L/Q

uNGB0LggINGC0YDQtdGC0YzQuNC8INC70LjRhtCw0LwhIC0tLSDQn9CQ0J4gJnF1

b3Q70JDQodCa0J4t0KHQotCg0JDQpdCe0JLQkNCd0JjQlSZxdW90Oy48L3NwYW4+

PC9wPg0KPC9ib2R5Pg0KPC9odG1sPg==



--------_19169_-917240200_470060--



--------_26500_-917240200_470060--
```

Answer (score 0):

он вам отдаёт строку в base64 формате. Для переформатирования спарсите сообщение без заголовков и используйте пакет base64 https://riptutorial.com/python/example/27070/encoding-and-decoding-base64